# How to implement localization of jquery smartwizard?

Tags: jquery, smart-wizard

is there a way to do the localization of package? eg. previous, next if switch to French should be précédente, suivante

Comment: Did you look at any of the [documentation](https://techlaboratory.net/jquery-smartwizard#optional-parameters)?  Maybe the [`lang:`](https://techlaboratory.net/jquery-smartwizard#param-lang) option?